# how can I draw a path with both solid and dotted line in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, path, dotted-line

I am new to wpf. Now I need to draw a image in style, using 'path' with both solid and dotted line like sample image.
I know how to draw with solid or dotted line, but have no idea about combine them in a path...

```
<Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="Path">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource ItemBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource ItemStroke}"/>
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>
    ...
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Vessel" TargetType="Path" BasedOn="{StaticResource ItemStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="..."/>
</Style>
```

Comment: A Path's Stroke is either dotted or not. You might need to draw two Paths with different Strokes.

Comment: *I need to draw a image in style, using 'path' with both solid and dotted line like sample image* What sample image?